# Where is the reset password key stored/generated?

Tags: password

Where is the reset password key stored in the wordpress DB? Is this the same as the user_activation_key? WP version 3.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From line 213 of wp-login.php:

```
    $wpdb->update($wpdb->users, array('user_activation_key' => $key), array('user_login' => $user_login));
```

So yes, the key is the `user_activation_key`. Don't know what you need to know that for but if you look in that file you'll see there are several ways to hook into it.